# jQuery Event Listener not listening

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, events

I'm trying to do a simple thing. Simply attach a click listener to my page:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.3
$(document).ready(function() {
    return $(document.body).on('click', '#container', function() {
        return console.log("hello");
    });
});
```

But I can't get the click events to register.

When I inspect the code in Firebug, I notice that it does recognize the event handler, but the function is not what I specified in the code:

[image]
[image]
[image]

From my kinda-intermediate javascript-knowing eyes, it looks like jQuery doesn't find that the element has a handler.

I have tried:

Reordering the loading of the scripts
Attaching to different elements, different events
Using event delegation
Inspecting all over with firebug

I created a jsFiddle to recreate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/wV5L3/

Any help would be great, bonus points for how I could have found the issue without consulting SO. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>It should be `"body"` instead of `document.body`</strike>

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").on('click', '#container', function(){
    console.log("hello");
  });
});
```

**EDIT** : When I tried your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wV5L3/) again, it seems to be working just fine. It is logging the output in console as intended. Am I missing something in question?

Comment: when I click on the quiz html, I don't see any logging. You do?

Comment: wow. that's crazy. I just upgraded to FireFox 29, and I swear its not accepting these clicks. I tried with Safari and Chrome and it works fine. So weird. It can't be that Firefox is broke, right?

Comment: It might be possible that something is wrong. Try restarting the browser and give it a go. You can also check if your site works on different platform as intended with some service like [BrowserStack](http://browserstack.com); helps in verify the things. :)

Comment: Okay, closing and restarting the browser fixed it. I feel dumb now. Literally spent hours troubleshooting this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using too much returns. Use this  -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document.body).on('click', '#container', function() {
        console.log("hello");
    });
});
```

Comment: removing the returns had no effect